# String request doesn't run in volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I want to make a login using Volley but I haven't data in the request. There aren't errors so I don't know what's wrong. I have one php script on a server that returns a json string and works correctly.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['correo'], $_POST['contrasenya']))
{
        $ecorreo = $_POST['correo'];
        $pwd = $_POST{'contrasenya'};

        if(!empty($ecorreo) && !empty($pwd))
        {
            $pwd_encriptada = md5($pwd);
            $this -> vresul = $this ->  usuario_existe($ecorreo,  
             $pwd_encriptada);

        }
        else
            $this -> vresul = "All fields must be filled";
    }
    else
        $this -> vresul = "Empty fields";   

    return $this -> vresul; //the json string returned
}

public function usuario_existe($prcorreo,$prcontrasenya)
{
    $this -> qry = "select * from usuarios where correo = ? and contrasenya = ?";
    $this -> sqry = $this -> conexion -> prepare($this -> qry);
    $this -> sqry -> execute(array($prcorreo,$prcontrasenya));

    $this -> result = $this -> sqry -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $this -> conexion = NULL;


    if(!empty($this -> result)) 
    {
        $this -> datos['correo'] = utf8_encode($this -> result['correo']);
        $this -> datos['contrasenya'] = utf8_encode($this -> result['contrasenya']);    

        $this -> resultado = json_encode($this -> datos);
    }
    else 
            $this -> resultado = "Incorrect user or password";

    return $this -> resultado;
}
```

}

The android code:

```
final String correo = entcorreo.getText().toString().trim();
final String contrasena = entcontrasenya.getText().toString().trim();

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginTienda.this);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,  
    Config.LOGIN_URL,new Response.Listener<String>()
         {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {

              Toast.makeText(LoginTienda.this,response,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //response is blank
             }

           },

            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError Error)
                {

                  Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), 
                  "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos",   
                   Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
```

After typing the user and the password correctly in the app the response is empty.
How can I get the response correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you debug on the server if the request is correct?

Comment: Yes, I test the script on the server using a form and it works.

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android:

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, YourUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        if (!response.equals(null)) {
            Log.e("Your Array Response", response);                    
        } else {
            Log.e("Your Array Response", "Data Null");
        }
    }

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("error is ", "" + error);
    }
}) {    

 //This is for Headers If You Needed
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        params.put("token", ACCESS_TOKEN);
        return params;
    }

 //Pass Your Parameters here
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("User", UserName);
        params.put("Pass", PassWord);
        return params;
    }
};
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
queue.add(request);
```

Comment: Yes. That runs but I realised that I need to type echo $vresult in the php script to work with toast. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line under RequestQueue :- requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

Comment: That's not the problem, since the OP **DOES** enter the `onResponse(String response)` event but the response is empty.

Comment: then check your Internet Permission.

Comment: I have the internet permission in the manifest and I add the line requestQueue.add(StringRequest) and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use toString() method on your response object?

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {

          try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                Toast.makeText(LoginTienda.this,response.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Or you can try to call your toast from the onResponse callback, like:

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            responseTxt = "our response: = " +response;
            showToast();

        }

        //(...)

        private void showToast() {

        Toast.makeText(LoginTienda.this, responseTxt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

If you want to pull your JSON values from php file, you have to made JSONObject. Try this:

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String correo = jObj.getString("correo"); //1st value
                    String contrasenya = jObj.getString("contrasenya"); //2nd value


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

         }
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. I tried both and in the first it I didn't watch anything on the screen and in the second the string our response. It's very strange.

Comment: That string is your response  from php file. If u want get your Json values you have to made JSONObject.